# Submitting a jquery form in FF

Tags: jquery, forms, firefox

I created a jquery element object (a form) with attributes as a plainObject ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-ownerDocument))

```
$('<form>', { 'action' : 'test.php', 'method' : 'post' })
.append($('<input>', { 'value' : 'test' }))
.submit()
```

This works perfectly in chrome but not in FF
is there any documentation i should read please or something I am missing in order to make this form submitted in FF ? Thanks

Comment: No errors, console.log is not working in FF thou .. Is it only in my computer ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code creates a form element, but never attaches it to the DOM. IIRC, Firefox won't submit a form that isn't in the DOM. So you'll need to put the form in the DOM in order to submit it.

The question is where to put it, since of course submitting the form replaces the content of the window it's in. You might create a zero-height `iframe`, put the `form` in that, and then submit it.

Or, of course, use ajax rather than a form.

Comment: I need to refresh the page so AJAX is not an option for me, thanks, i can also add a display none for the input or the form then insert it without any more elements. Thanks alot for your help i will try it first

Comment: @user6436578: If you need to refresh the page with the result of submitting the form, then it's really easy: Add `.appendTo(document.body)` before `.submit`.